# Exponential to trigonometric conversion in SymPy while simplifying - a stubborn expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have been trying to simplify

```
exp(2*I*N) - 1)**2/((exp(2*I*N) - 1)**2 - 4*exp(2*I*N)*cos(N)**2)
```

Where the answer should be (sin N)^2, but the output is same as input.

I have tried `.rewrite(cos)` and then simplify, trigsimp, expand and pretty much all I could discover quickly from help sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting in terms of `exp` instead of `cos` is more helpful:

```
expr.rewrite(exp).simplify()
```

returns `-cos(2*N)/2 + 1/2` which is visibly equivalent to `sin(N)**2`. Clean it up with

```
expr.rewrite(exp).simplify().trigsimp()
```

getting `sin(N)**2`

---

Old answer, might still be of value: You probably meant `N` to be real, so let's declare it as such.

Given a mix of complex exponentials and trigonometric functions, it will probably help to separate the real and imaginary parts with `as_real_imag()`. A direct application does not do much beyond putting re(...) and im(...), so rewriting in exponentials and expanding the squares/products is advisable first:

```
N = symbols('N', real=True)
expr = (exp(2*I*N) - 1)**2/((exp(2*I*N) - 1)**2 - 4*exp(2*I*N)*cos(N)**2)
result = [a.trigsimp() for a in expr.rewrite(cos).expand().as_real_imag()]
```

Result:    `[sin(N)**2, 0]`, meaning the real and imaginary parts of the expression. It can be recombined into a single expression with `result[0] + I*result[1]`.

Comment: New answer is totally awesome! The first one didn’t work with expression having multiple such terms, but this does!