# symbolic complex expression simplification

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

Although my question is related to a specific problem, I would like to approach it in more general terms.
I would like to simplify a  fractional complex expression obtained  by multiplying symbolic matrices using the sympy package.
What I get is a fraction with real parameters and many complex exponential terms (phase terms) like exp(-j*d), exp(-2j*d) and also exp(-4j*d). I get the correct result, but when I try to calculate the ||**2, which is a real expression, sympy.simplify() is not able to manage the phase terms and I obtain a huge expression I have to reduce by hand.
My test procedure, being T, M, M_inv, F and T, 2x2 symbolic matrices is:

```
import simply as sym
Mf = T @ M_inv @ F @ T
Mf = sym.simplify(Mf)
eig = Mf.eigenvals() 
for key,value in eig.items():
    val = key
eig_cc = np.conj(val)
final = sym.simplify(val*eig_cc)
```

I wonder if a specific tool exists to improve the calculation.

After a fast research I found two possibilities in the post:

[Exponential to trigonometric conversion in SymPy while simplifying - a stubborn expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722676/exponential-to-trigonometric-conversion-in-sympy-while-simplifying-a-stubborn)

1. a.trigsimp() for a in expr.rewrite(cos).expand().as_real_imag()
2. expr.rewrite(cos).simplify().trigsimp()

While the first provides the correct result for easier expressions (not for the one I am trying to solve), none of them works in my case.

Second question, eig output has a dict shape, so to take the value I used the for loop.

```
for key,value in eig.items():
    val = key
```

Is there a better, faster, way to achieve the same result?

The code I am using is:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *
t = sym.Symbol('t', real=True)
r = sym.Symbol('r', real=True)
u = sym.Symbol('u', real=True)
d = sym.Symbol('d', real=True)
a = sym.Symbol('a', real=True)


I = np.identity(2)

T = sym.Matrix ([[t,0],[0,t]])
R = sym.Matrix ([[r,0],[0,r]])
F = sym.Matrix ([[sym.sqrt(u)*sym.exp(-1j*d),0],[0,sym.sqrt(u)*sym.exp(-1j*d)]])



sym.init_printing()
M = (I - F @ R @ F @ R)
M_inv = M.inv() 

Mf = T @ M_inv @ F @ T

Mf = sym.simplify(Mf)

eig = Mf.eigenvals()



for key,value in eig.items():
    val = key

eig_cc = np.conj(val)
expr = finale = sym.simplify(val*eig_cc)

"""
Test1
"""

result = [a.trigsimp() for a in expr.rewrite(sin).expand().as_real_imag()]

"""
Test2
"""

result1 = expr.rewrite(sin).simplify().trigsimp()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you make a minimal complete code example? Without being able to see any of the expressions you are referring to it's hard to answer what would work.

Comment: yes, I have just added the code to my post. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. Don't mix up numpy and sympy like this unless you know exactly what you are doing. There is no need to use numpy at all here so use e.g. `sym.eye(2)` and `sym.conjugate(val)`
2. Don't use floats unless you have a good reason - use `sym.I` instead of `1j`. Using numpy can potentially introduce floats so don't do that unless you know what you are doing.
3. Although `eigenvals` returns a dict in this case you only care about the values of the dict so you can just do `list(M.eigenvals())`.
4. Although you declare all symbols as real you are using `sqrt(u)` which is real only if `u` is positive. Unless you intend for `sqrt(u)` to be potentially imaginary then `u` should be declared as positive.

With the above changes your code looks like this:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *
t = sym.Symbol('t', real=True)
r = sym.Symbol('r', real=True)
u = sym.Symbol('u', positive=True)
d = sym.Symbol('d', real=True)
a = sym.Symbol('a', real=True)

I = sym.eye(2)

T = sym.Matrix ([[t,0],[0,t]])
R = sym.Matrix ([[r,0],[0,r]])
F = sym.Matrix ([[sym.sqrt(u)*sym.exp(-sym.I*d),0],[0,sym.sqrt(u)*sym.exp(-sym.I*d)]])

sym.init_printing()
M = (I - F @ R @ F @ R)
M_inv = M.inv()

Mf = T @ M_inv @ F @ T

Mf = sym.simplify(Mf)

[eig] = Mf.eigenvals()

expr = eig * sym.conjugate(eig)
```

Now the final expression `expr` is this:

```
In [8]: expr
Out[8]: 
               4                
              t ⋅u              
────────────────────────────────
⎛ 2      -2⋅ⅈ⋅d⎞ ⎛ 2      2⋅ⅈ⋅d⎞
⎝r ⋅u - ℯ      ⎠⋅⎝r ⋅u - ℯ     ⎠

In [9]: expr.expand()
Out[9]: 
                  4                   
                 t ⋅u                 
──────────────────────────────────────
 4  2    2    2⋅ⅈ⋅d    2    -2⋅ⅈ⋅d    
r ⋅u  - r ⋅u⋅ℯ      - r ⋅u⋅ℯ       + 1

In [10]: expr.expand().rewrite(sin)
Out[10]: 
                                   4                                    
                                  t ⋅u                                  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 4  2    2                               2                              
r ⋅u  - r ⋅u⋅(-ⅈ⋅sin(2⋅d) + cos(2⋅d)) - r ⋅u⋅(ⅈ⋅sin(2⋅d) + cos(2⋅d)) + 1

In [11]: expr.expand().rewrite(sin).expand()
Out[11]: 
             4             
            t ⋅u           
───────────────────────────
 4  2      2               
r ⋅u  - 2⋅r ⋅u⋅cos(2⋅d) + 1
```

I presume that the final result there is the one that you wanted.